# adding row value to total if condition (don't know how to ask this)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a points system for companies where every employee that works for that company is worth some points.
Every month the points for the companies are calculated.
This works so far, however In the 9th month of this year I would like to give double points for each acquired employee in that month.
I don't know how to do that.
I have this query now:

```
SELECT company, (employees *2) as "Points" 
FROM data 
WHERE month = '10' 
GROUP BY company
```

But as you can see I give 2 points for each employee that works for that company in that month.
But for month 9 I want to give double points and add them to current points in current month(10)

I have this SQLfiddle as example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cb812/7

Expected result:

```
company     Points
__________________
company 1   26 + (extra points from month 9)
company 2   32 + (extra points from month 9)
company 3   44 + (extra points from month 9)
```

Comment: Could you show us your expect result?

Comment: Ill add it to the sqlfiddle

Comment: why do you have a group by? That should result in an error. Perhaps you want the sum of employees ?

Comment: @KristjanKica no I want to see the points for each company for current month, but the double points for month 9 needs to be added

Comment: @HenkKrens Please add expected output in a "tabular format" to the question itself. Just comments in SQL fiddle are not making sense.

Comment: On a sidenote: The table looks a bit strange containing a month but no year.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner in my real one I have, but its explained a lot easier like this

Comment: So if we run the query in, say, Januay, it is supposed to calculate January points (January employees times two) plus the difference of employees from August to September times four. Yes?

Comment: Looks like Window function with frame problem. Do you have access to MySQL server version >= **8.0.2** ?

Comment: For january 2019 yes, but for 2018 not because that month isn't been yet then. Each row in my Db is not filled with the difference, but with the total for that month.

Comment: Oh, the task is getting more and more weird. So it's all about the August/September delta 2018. If you run the query for any month before September 2018 (June 2018, May 2012, whatever), you just want to get the current month's points. If you run the query for any month after August 2018 (December 2018, March 2022, ...) you want the 2018 bonus points added. Yes?

Comment: Yes Thorsten (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So it's all about the August/September delta 2018. If you run the query for any month before September 2018 (June 2018, May 2012, whatever), you just want to get the current month's points. If you run the query for any month after August 2018 (December 2018, March 2022, ...) you want the 2018 bonus points added.

Group by company and use conditional aggregation (an aggregation function on a condition) in order to calculate this.

We must look at the requested month (e.g. 10/2018) and August 2018 and September 2018.

```
SET @yearmonth = '201810';

SELECT
  company, 
  SUM(
   CASE WHEN yearmonth = @yearmonth THEN employees * 2 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN @yearmonth >= '201809' AND yearmonth = '201809' THEN employees * 4 ELSE 0 END -
   CASE WHEN @yearmonth >= '201809' AND yearmonth = '201808' THEN employees * 4 ELSE 0 END
  ) AS points
FROM data
WHERE yearmonth in ('201808', '201809', @yearmonth)
GROUP BY company
ORDER BY company;
```

The `WHERE` clause is superfluous, as the months are checked inside the SUM function, but it may speed up the query.

Rextester demo: https://rextester.com/ELOWTL44361